# Query using previous query's result

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT value FROM table WHERE column = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("i", $number);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE column = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $result); // error on this line
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result2);
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

**I want to use the result from the first query in the second query**, however, I get the following error on line `$stmt->bind_param("i", $result);`:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

What's wrong?

Comment: if you're using that actual code `SELECT value FROM table WHERE column = ?`, `table` is a reserved MySQL word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html and needs to be inside back ticks. Plus if your value is not an integer `i` then it will produce an error, if that is not whats being passed as a value. If it's a string, then use `s` - the answer is practically in the error message.

Comment: Don't loop queries. >_< You can actually do it all in one query. More efficient and safer.

Comment: No, they're just placement values I put in. They're different in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Your second call to `$cxn->prepare` is returning `false` or `null`. The second query is failing to create a statement, in other words. As one of the comments mentioned, it could be due to your use of a reserved word (`table`), a syntax error, or because the connection timed out, etc.

Assuming this is something like [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), you need to check that your calls to `prepare` are returning a statement:

```
<?php
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT value FROM table WHERE column = ?');
if (!$stmt) {
    // do something to deal with the failure
    // throw new \Exception('Could not create statement');
}
$stmt->bind_param("i", $number);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE column = ?');
    if (!$stmt) {
         // failed, handle it
         // throw new \Exception('Could not create statement');
    }
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $result); // error on this line
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result2);
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Or you can set PDO's error mode to throw exceptions and `catch` when things go wrong.

```
<?php
$cxn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// after the above, failing calls to $cnx->prepare will throw exceptions
```

If it is PDO, you can use [`PDO::errorInfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) and `PDO::errorCode` to track down your problem:

```
<?php
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT value FROM table WHERE column = ?');
if (!$stmt) {
    var_dump($cxn->errorInfo());
    return;
}
```

`errorInfo` will give you back an array with the SQLSTATE code as the first element, a driver specific error code as the second, and an actual error message as the third. That's the place to start finding why your queries are failing. If you do set your connection to throw exceptions the [exception itself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) will have the information you need (`PDOException::getMessage`, `PDOException::$errorInfo`, etc).

Comment: Yeah, it's returning false, but I have no idea why.

Comment: See my edit: if it's PDO, you can use `errorInfo` to start tracking that down.

Comment: So it turns out I had to add `$stmt->close();` after the first query, but I'm not sure why. Can you explain?