# Mysqli Prepare is not working inside another prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to run a prepared statement inside a prepared statement but got no success. Here is my code:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT author_id FROM posts")) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($author_id);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if ($stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=? LIMIT 1")) {
            $stmt2->bind_param("s", $author_id);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->bind_result($username);
            $stmt2->fetch();
            $stmt2->close();

            //showing username
            echo $username;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

I am getting `author id` from a table and then from `author id` I'm trying to get author's name from another table.
Can you please tell me any way to do this or any modification in this script can get it done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613630/query-using-previous-querys-result/19614121#19614121

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes PHP section of this site makes my eyes aching. Not only question lacks very basic knowledge in every aspect of programming, but also answers promote terrible practices.

1. You have to **report errors** to make yourself aware of the certain reason. Either usual way, via `$conn->error` or by setting mysqli in exception mode.
2. After reading the error message, you can google for a solution - `store_result()`
3. For such a dataset, NO loop needed ever, as you have to use **JOIN** instead:

And so whole code become

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$sql = "SELECT username FROM posts p, users u WHERE u.id=author_id";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row()) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Yeah! I did that before you asked but forgot to tell here. `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`.  
You asked to use join instead but I am using prepared statements, I think they don't allow that.

Comment: You have very strange idea about prepared statements

Comment: Can you please guide me? The way I am trying to do it, php and Mysql is saying commands out of sync.

Comment: DO IT IN ONE QUERY and there will be nothing to be out of sync

Answer (score -2):

Use another mysqli object for inner loop.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(host, user, password, dbname);
$mysqli2 = new mysqli(host, user, password, dbname);

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT author_id FROM posts")) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($author_id);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($stmt2 = $mysqli2->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt2->bind_param("s", $author_id);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->bind_result($username);
        $stmt2->fetch();
        $stmt2->close();

        //showing username
        echo $username;
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Plus, there's a misuse of prepare. It must be inited outside the loop. As it is written now it will reinitialize prepared statement at every step and will work even slower then simple mysqli->query

Comment: @AlexanderKouznetsov Can you Please suggest any other way to do this?